# Tracking errors from z/os's syslog

Tags: syslog, mainframe, zos

I need to reference the errors related to jobs present in the syslog.

Is it preferable to use messages from the ordonnancer e.g EQQE036I (TWS) or those from MVS e.g IEF451I, IEF452I etc ...

Comment: Your question is not really a good fit for StackOverflow. Since we can have no necessary knowledge of what you want, we could only offer opinions, for free, You have to look at the Help Centre (see under help on the top bar) and see if you can phrase a question on this within the requirements of the site. Then you can either edit this, or ask a new question, or try to ask this exact question somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends: If there are TWS-specific errors you have to track them using the EQQ messages. Otherwise I'd go for the scheduler-independent and probably more detailed MVS messages.

And most of these messages haven't changed much in decades.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If they use TWS, the EQQ messages will always appear in the syslog or it depends of the company's policies ?